# Relocating/Moving house

Tags: vocabulary

I asked a question on one of the stackexchange sites and one user edited a sentence I made from "We were relocating so we...." to "We were moving house so we....". As an english speaker, I have never heard of "moving house" in context of relocation in a sentence before. Presently I am even doubting if relocating is correct in the context of :

*"Moving all your belongings in a house you onced rented into a newly rented house"*

Comment: What do you mean by 'never heard of "moving house"' , there are countless examples : [lengusa](https://lengusa.com/search/moving%20house), what I am missing ? 'moving' and 'relocation' have been used in same contexts but not with "moving house" [lengusa](https://lengusa.com/search/moving%20house%20relocation)

Comment: My impression is that moving house includes moving all (or most of) my belongings to my new home, whereas relocating could also apply to a situation where I sell all my furniture along with my previous home and buy new furniture for my new home.

Answer (score 2):

[british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english)

*Relocating* connotes a permanent move to an entirely new area (or even country) usually in order to take up a new job. Employment offers may include "relocation assistance" and wouldn't normally say "help with moving costs". In British English, it's jargon; and even *relocate* is defined in terms of *move*:

> **relocate**
>
> Move to a new place and establish one’s home or business there:
>   *sixty workers could face redundancy because the firm is relocating*
>   [with object]: *distribution staff will be relocated to Holland*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/relocate)

"Moving house" or simply "moving" is more common in British English than "relocating". There's even a website called HelpIAmMoving.com, which demonstrates the usage:

> Moving house in is stressful. By thinking ahead and planning early it doesn't have to be as stressful. Here are our top tips...
>
> Don't move on a Friday. Even though the weekend gives you time to settle in to your new pad, in reality it is the worst day of the week to move house.

*Moving* **generally** only means moving house, while keeping the same job and possibly other contacts, although it can indicate a permanent move entirely away. *Relocation* always means a permanent move entirely away.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the name of the dictionary you used? I thought it was standard practice to write in full, the name of the  reference cited. [*"This is not acceptable because the source of the quote is not cited in plain text. It doesn't matter if the headword here is a link; the source — which is ODO in this case — must appear in plain text."*](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5196/44619) :D I see little difference in directly linking a key word to an online resource, or using an abbreviation, if I still have to hover my mouse over the link to see its full name.

Comment: How about a more casual word for relocation in an informal daily conversation?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @AndrewLeach that *relocation* means moving entirely away, usually with a change of job. For a specific word that means moving house, consider the verb *flit* (EOD reference [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=flit&searchmode=none)), which is still in wide use in Scotland and Northern England, and its noun *flitting*.

Answer (score 0):

Denotations for 'relocate' differ according to which dictionary you choose to believe:

> **relocate** ... v.i.
>
> 1. to change one's residence or place of business; move. [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010]

vs

> **relocate** v.intr.
>
> To become established in a new residence of place of business:
>   relocated in Ohio. [AHDEL]

Though I'd also be swayed in my choice of words by connotation.